# Recieving desired output but error message tags along

Tags: ruby

I am passing all of the tests for this kata yet still receiving some errors. The codewars website does not allow me to see all the test cases, so with my inexperienced eyes it is hard to see the issue. Any explanation for what I am seeing is greatly appreciated. My method is to parse for nil, split digits into an array, and evaluate the first one for even/odd and place it into the new array with/out "-" accordingly, and removing each first element as I iterate through.

Dashatize:

Given a number, return a string with dash'-'marks before and after each odd integer, but do not begin or end the string with a dash mark.

Ex:

```
dashatize(274) -> '2-7-4'
dashatize(6815) -> '68-1-5'

def dashatize(num)
  if num.nil?
    "nil"
  else
    arr2 = []
    arr = num.digits.reverse
    arr2 << arr[0]
    arr.shift
    until arr == [] do
      if arr[0].even? && arr2[-1].to_i.even?
        arr2 << arr[0].to_s
        arr.shift
      else
        arr2 << "-"
        arr2 << arr[0].to_s
        arr.shift
      end
    end
    arr2.join
  end
end
```

I pass all tests but still fail the kata due to this:

```
#<Math::DomainError: out of domain> main.rb:10:in `digits' 
main.rb:10:in `dashatize' main.rb:39:in `block (2 levels) in <main>' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:180:in `wrap_error' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:72:in `it' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:206:in `it' main.rb:36:in `block in <main>' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:55:in `block in describe' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:46:in `measure' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:51:in `describe' 
/runner/frameworks/ruby/cw-2.rb:202:in `describe' main.rb:29:in 
`<main>'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6/Math/DomainError.html):

> Math::DomainError Raised when a mathematical function is evaluated
>   outside of its domain of definition.

You're calling the `#digits` function on the input, which is probably negative for some example in the test cases and you get the error mentioned above.

So again, doing this:

```
-1.digits
```

Will give you an error like you got:

```
out of domain
():1:in `digits'
():1:in `<main>'
```

You have to use something other than `#digits` or make it positive first or find some other solution.

On a side note, here' my approach to the problem:

```
def dashatize(number)
  number.to_s
  .gsub(/[13579]/, '-\\0-')
  .gsub('--','-')
  .delete_suffix('-')
  .delete_prefix('-')
end

dashatize(68145) 
#=>"68-1-4-5"
dashatize(6815)
#=>"68-1-5"
dashatize(274)
#=> "2-7-4"
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess @Viktor already caught the reason: maybe the test case uses negative numbers.
You can fix your code changing your line `arr = num.digits.reverse` using [Integer#abs](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Integer.html#method-i-abs) to:

```
arr = num.abs.digits.reverse
```

Side note, a shorter version using the array of digits ([Array#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.6.5/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when)):

```
num.abs.digits.reverse.slice_when { |a, b| a.odd? || b.odd? }.map(&:join).join('-')
```